# CiviCRM Community Forums

Tags: logging

may I know where to report an issue with "CiviCRM Community Forums" (forum.civicrm.org) pls? 
I have been able to create an account and start a thread but one day later, impossible to log in again: wrong password they say.
The strange thing is my id/pwd is still ok on civicrm.org.
Is there a kind a miscommunication betwen the sub domain and the domain?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would register an account on https://chat.civicrm.org (I don't think it shares logins with the rest of civicrm.org but maybe that's changed).  Go into the "infrastructure" channel and someone should be able to fix any issues.